# Status code 405 for Restful Service call from jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, restful-url

I have created a restful service and trying to call it from webpage.
but i am getting **error code 405.**

***the same rest service call works fine with soap UI***

below are the details of wevservice and the jquery call

**webservice api**

> [OperationContract]
>           [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
>   UriTemplate = "PostMethodWithCustomerArray")]
>           List PostMethodWithCustomerArray(List dataStrings);

**Webservice code**

```
    public List<CustomerWithArray> PostMethodWithCustomerArray(List<CustomerWithArray> dataStrings)
    {
        return dataStrings;
    }
```

**ajax call**

```
var UrlPostMethodWithCustomerArray = "http://localhost:29745/RESTfulService.svc/PostMethodWithCustomerArray";

    var customerWithArray = [{ "Name": "Dipak Godbole", "Age": "27", "HumanType": "1", "strArray": ["11", "22"] },
   { "Name": "Madan Chapa", "Age": "19", "HumanType": "3", "strArray": ["111", "222"] },
   { "Name": "Raju Rohida", "Age": "55", "HumanType": "2", "strArray": ["1111", "2222"] }];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: UrlPostMethodWithparam, // Location of the service
        data: JSON.stringify(customerWithArray),
        dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call

            $.each(msg, function (index, item) {
                alert(item.Name + item.HumanType);
            });
            //alert(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
});
```

**Web Config sections**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TrialRESTService.RESTfulService" behaviorConfiguration="svcbehaviour">  
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="TrialRESTService.IRESTfulService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="svcbehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
         <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>



</configuration>
```

any help on this????

**Error using Google crome developer tools**

```
    OPTIONS 
    http://localhost:29745/RESTfulService.svc/PostMethodWithCustomerArray 
   405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery-1.8.2.min.js:19

 XMLHttpRequest cannot load     http://localhost:29745/RESTfulService.svc/PostMethodWithCustomerArray. Invalid HTTP status code 405 Default.aspx:1
```

Comment: did adding <enableWebScript/> help?

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect for your data payload (not valid json):

```
data: JSON.stringify("Dipak Godbole")
```

Instead you should have

```
data: JSON.stringify("{name: Dipak Godbole}")
```

You should check out this SO post. It has to do with cross domain issues: [Post data to RESTful Invalid HTTP status code 405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825458/post-data-to-restful-invalid-http-status-code-405)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<enableWebScript/>` in behaviour configuration of webHttpBinding endpoint as in below example.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WCF.TestWCF" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCFBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCF.ITestWCF" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCFEndPointBehaviour"></endpoint>     

  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWCFBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWCFEndPointBehaviour">
      <enableWebScript/>
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: i have used uritemplate hence after adding enablewebscript it gives the erro "Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'. "

Comment: can u remove uri template n try?

Comment: in that case getting "404" :(